# Show inequality (max, min)

Tags: inequality

How do I show this inequality

$$d(x,z) \leq \max(d(x,y), d(y,z))$$

when

$$\mu (x,y) = \min\{n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ x_n \not= y_n \}$$

and

$$d(x,y) = \frac{1}{\mu(x,y)}$$

What I've done so far:

$$d(x,z) = \frac{1}{\mu(x,z)} \Leftrightarrow \mu (x,z) = \frac{1}{d(x,z)} = \min\{n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ x_n \not= z_n\}$$

Therefore

$$\min\{n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ x_n \not= z_n\} \leq \min\{\{n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ x_n \not= y_n\},\{ n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ y_n \not= z_n \}\} $$

I can't seem to figure out where to go from here.

EDIT: Does any rules apply to the following?

$$\frac{1}{\mu(x,z)} \leq \frac{1}{\min\{  \mu(x,y), \mu(y,z) \}} $$

$x_n, y_n, z_n$ are sequences that are either 0 or 1.

Comment: Right, thanks. Corrected :)

Comment: Can you explain what kind of things are $x,y, x_n,y_n$? Real numbers, or vectors and components, or sequences?

Comment: Added it to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\mu(x,y)=n_{1}$ is finite,and $\mu(y,z)=n_{2}$ is finite. Then given, for all $n < n_{1}$ $x_{n}=y_{n}$ and $n<n_{2}$, $y_{n} = z_{n}$, hence for all $n<min\lbrace n_{1},n_{2} \rbrace$ $x_{n} =z_{n}$, so $\mu(x,z) \geq min \lbrace n_{1},n_{2} \rbrace$ sp $d(x,z) \leq max \lbrace \frac{1}{n_{1}},\frac{1}{n_{2}}\rbrace = max \lbrace d(x,y),d(y,z)\rbrace$. Notice that $\frac{1}{min\lbrace n_{1},n_{2} \rbrace}=max\lbrace \frac{1}{n_{1}}, \frac{{1}}{n_{2}}\rbrace$

Comment: Why is $x_n = y_n$ when $n<n_1$?

Comment: The definition of $\mu(x,y)$  is the smallest integer at which $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ differ! So they all agree at all integers before $n_{1}$.

Comment: I don't follow. If $x_n \not= y_n$, the definition of $\mu(x,y)$, then how can $x_n = y_n$?

Comment: $\mu(x,y)$ is the smallest integer $n$ for which $x_{n} \not =y_{n}$ eg : $\mu(x,y)=2$ if $x_{n}=n, y_{n}=n^{2}$. Let $n_{1} = \mu(x,y)$. If $n<n_{1}$, since $n_{1}$ is the minimal integer at which $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ differ, then for all integers strictly less than it, $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$  must be equal.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I know what you mean. I understand that $n_1$ is the minimal integer at which $x_n$ and $y_n$ differ. But I still don't get how $x_n = y_n$.
Is it possible to solve it in another way using the method I've written in the description?

Comment: Let $n<n_{1}$. I claim that $x_{n}=y_{n}$, for all $n<n_{1}$. Assume not, then, by well ordering property we can find an integer $n_{0}<n_{1}$ such that $x_{n_{0}}\not =y_{n_{0}}$, contadicting minimality of $n_{1}$.

Comment: Is it because if $n < n_1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there isn't any number between $n$ and $n_1$, hence $x_n$ HAVE to be equal to $y_n$?

Comment: No... could you determine $\mu(x,y)$ for the following pairs? 1) $x_{n}=n^{2}, y_{n}=n^{3}$, 2) $x_{n}=n, y_{n}=n+3$, 3) $x_{n}=(n-1)(n-2) , y_{n} = 0$. You will hopefully see what I mean.

Comment: 1) $x_n$, 2) $x_n$, 3) $y_n$

Comment: Your answer should be an integer...you can read again the definition of $\mu(x,y)$.

Comment: Then would it be 1) $2$, 2) $1$, 3) $ -1$?

Comment: 1) $\mu=2$, 2) $\mu=1$, 3)$\mu=3$. $\mu(x,y)$ is the smallest integer at which $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ differ. Let s take the first example : $x_{1}=1^{2}=1$ and $y_{1}=1^{3}=1$ so $x_{1}=y_{1}$ now $x_{2}=4, y_{2}=8$ and hence are different, so $\mu(x,y)=2$.

Comment: I see, but for me that still doesn't explain how $x_n = y_n$ when $n<n_1$

Comment: I actually think I understand now. I hope it's okay to ask another question. How do you go from $n<\min\{n_1, n_2\}$ to $\mu (x,z) \geq \min\{n_1,n_2\}$?

Comment: So, we said that for $n<n_{1}$ we have $x_{n}=y_{n}$, and for $n<n_{2}$ we have $y_{n}=z_{n}$. Now let $n_{0}$ be the minimum of $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$. Then $n_{0} \leq n_{1}$ and $n_{0} \leq n_{2}$, hence for all $n<n_{0} (\leq n_{1})$ we have $x_{n}=y_{n}$ and for all $n<n_{0} (\leq n_{2})$ we have $y_{n}=z_{n}$, hence for all $n<n_{0}$ we have $x_{n}=z_{n}$, if $x_{n}$ and $z_{n}$ differ, then it is at an integer greater or equal than $n_{0}$, as they agree for all integers strictly less than $n_{0}$.

Comment: I slept on it and it actually makes sense to me now. Thank you very much for the help!